# VS19 "Highlight references to symbol under cursor" off equivalent for C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to turn off the auto highlighting of symbols under the cursor.

In C# this is here:

[image]

However I can't find the matching option for the C/C++ editor

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is under Text Editor → C/C++ → Advanced → Disable Reference Highlighting:

[image]

Considering the unfortunate use of a double-negative, you'll want to set that option to "True" in order to disable that automatic highlighting of references.